# how can I use sympy to add expressions with index

Tags: python, loops, sympy

I have a dataframe in pandas, the first columns is named `x0` and the second is `x1`. It has many(like 100) rows. Thus I have 100 groups of `[x0,x1]`, and then I want to generate a long expression with every related to one group. More clearly, the task I want to do is to generate a expression:

```
exp(b0*x00+b1*x10)+exp(b0*x01+b1*x11)+...exp(b0*(x0 100) + b1*(x1 100))
```

`b0` and `b1` are both unknown value (symbols) here and I will find their solution later on.

In brief, I need to expression `sigma(exp(b0*x0+b1*x1))` and the sigma has 100 items with `x0,x1 n` a dataframe, but I don't know how to program the loop.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps, i'm not familiar with Panda, but you need the [summation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/tutorial.html)(f, (i, a, b)) from sympy.

essentially, you will just need to declare something like expr = summation(exp, (i, 0, 101))
in this case, your 'exp' function already has symbolic b0 and b1 terms inside it.

and when you want to pretty print it out, you just need to use pprint(expr) instead of print().

Answer (score 0):

A simple python for-loop would suffice to generate that expression:

```
>>> import numpy as np  # pandas uses numpy arrays
>>> import sympy as sym
>>> x = np.random.rand(5,2).view(dtype=[('x0', np.float), ('x1', np.float)])
>>> b0, b1 = sym.symbols('b0 b1')
>>> x['x0']  # to show the contents
array([[ 0.1389724 ],
       [ 0.14091647],
       [ 0.08886302],
       [ 0.48792306],
       [ 0.749205  ]])
>>> expr = 0
>>> for x0, x1 in zip(x['x0'], x['x1']): 
...     # build up the expression term by term:
...     expr += sym.exp(b0 * float(x0) + b1 *float(x1))
... 
>>> expr
exp(0.0888630154325879*b0 + 0.597823474111901*b1) + exp(0.138972400914926*b0 + 0.0275642343608167*b1) + exp(0.140916465250792*b0 + 0.0662746588259522*b1) + exp(0.487923064546991*b0 + 0.922545565808876*b1) + exp(0.7492050039088*b0 + 0.911117507753871*b1)
```